# Google App Engine: Upload returns 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload data through the Google App Engine bulkload but I get this error

```
08:51 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20140425.205147
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
404 Not Found

The resource could not be found.


--- end server output ---
FINISHED
```

Comment: Have you enabled remote api in the builtins sections of app.yaml ?

Comment: Yes I did it like 
builtins:
- remote_api: on

Comment: Well that leaves you with 2 possibilities, either your using the incorrect appid or specifying the incorrent URL explicitly, or your mistaken.  Have you checked to see if you can use the remote_api_shell, both depend on /_ah/remote_api being accessible. The only way you could get a 404 is one of the above scenarios. What is your command line

Comment: upload_data --config_file=<AbsolutePathOfTheLoaderPyFile> --filename=<AbsolutePathOfTheDataCSVFile> --url=http://<correctAppID>.appspot.com/remote_api

Comment: There is your problem then URL is incorrect.  By default it should be `--url=http://<correctAppID>.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api`

Comment: oops it was the missing _ah! What does it stand for!? Anyway it works now thank you

Comment: `_ah` is fundamentally part of the URL, google use the `_ah` prefix for a number of the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your problem then URL is incorrect. By default it should be

```
 --url=http://<correctAppID>.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```